How to copy compiled tailwind styles to separate static file in next.js?
I'm trying to host a copy of tailwind compiled styles that are usually inlined to page's  tag to a separate file for microfrontend import in module federation. My tailwind styles are in src/shared/styles/tailwind.css file and global css is in src/shared/styles/global.css, both are imported in src/pages/_app.ts
Basically I want next.js webpack config that: 1. compiles all css normally 2. extracts tailwind's generated css to separate file, say localhost:1234/_next/static/css/tailwind.css so I can later import it with module federation plugin thus copying tailwind styles to host app from remote microfrontend.
I tried using mini-css-extract-plugin like this:
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack(config, { webpack, isServer, dev }) {
    config.optimization = {
      ...config.optimization
    }

    if (!isServer) {
      const plugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'static/css/tailwind.css'
      })
      config.plugins.push(plugin)

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /tailwind\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ],
      })
  }
}

but this causes Internal Server Error:
error - ./src/shared/styles/global.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

meaning I somehow overwrited default css loader and now it won't load any css files
I tried changing test to /tailwind\.css$/, and remove exclude, but then I got another error:

  2 | export {};
  3 |     if(module.hot) {
> 4 |       (function() {
    |       ^
  5 |         var localsJsonString = undefined;
  6 |         // 1713624116555

I tried different positions of plugins in use: ['css-loader','postcss-loader', { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader }] results in
Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @tailwind base;
| @tailwind components;
| @tailwind utilities;
|

The idea is to use postcss-loader to compile tailwind (I have postcss.config.js config) and then use MiniCssExtractPlugin to extract it to static/css/tailwind.css file in .next directory, but also inline it into the page as usual
